# Joblib, Parallel and batch_size

Tags: parallel-processing, joblib, batchsize

Let's say I have a generator/list of size 50000. And, I want to use it as:

```
batches = range(0, 50001)

Parallel(n_jobs=multiprocessing.cpu_count(), verbose=100,
                 backend="threading", batch_size=?, pre_dispatch=?)(delayed(<function>)(it) for it in batches)
```

Can you please tell me what would be the correct value in batch_size and pre_dispatch if I want to process 20,000 items at a single time/or I want a thread/cpu to process 20,000 items as a single task?

Answer (score 0):

To process on a single CPU 20000 items, batch_size=20000.

Predispatch is by default sent to 2*CPU-s. In the logic of keeping the CPU-s busy, probably it should be 2*batch_size, so pre_dispatch=40000. It is also tempting to set pre_dispatch='all' however that works if tasks are roughly equivalent in time. 2*batch_size, to avoid one CPU being idle, if there is a big discrepancy in time/task.

In my own experience, it is better to have a higher batch_size if each operation is fast, to reduce I/O.